# Tetris: What is the Polyomino (max 3x3) with the least probability of being useful to the player?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, packing-problem

I am currently programming a Tetris game and I want to add a custom Polyomino to the game with a maximum size of 3x3. I want this Polyomino to be the most disruptive figure, which means it to be not useful for the player in the highest amount of cases, with which I mean that it will not be helpful to fill up one row and that it will make it harder to fill up rows in consecutive turns.

Now I have to consider not only the possible states at the bottom, but also what states the custom Polyomino will leave the bottom in.

I was thinking of the 3x3 Block with a hole in the middle, since you have to have 3 empty fields in a sequence in order to place it beneficially, which reduces the amount of possible beneficial bottom states, which I consider to be 3 in a row with all combinations of occupied fields, to 1 in 7 and would lead to creating a state where the row, that will be occupied by the middle of the block will always be blocked until the row on the top is resolved.

But is there a way to calculate if the 3x3 Block with the hole in the middle is really the most undesirable Polyomino in most combinations of states? Do I have to consider something else?

Edit:

With the bottom states I mean that of course there will always be many places to drop the Polyomino, but looking at the bottom as a sequence of 3 fields in a row, you get the 7 cases:

1. not a single field is occupied
2. only the left field is occupied
3. only the middle field is occupied
4. only the right field is occupied
5. the left and the middle field are occupied
6. the left and the right fields are occupied
7. the middle and the right fields are occupied

Now what I mean with beneficially is that placing the block can

1. help filling up the current row
2. not create a row that is harder or impossible to fill up until a row above is resolved (unreachable holes)

While the T-shaped block is beneficial in all situations, the stair-shaped block can never be beneficial in situation 1 and either situation 2 and 5 or situation 4 and 7. This is because the T-shape can be rotated always to either fill up the sequence of 3 fields or it can at least be placed in a way, that the player does not get any unreachable holes in the board. The stair-shaped Tetromino on the other hand will always place an unreachable hole in e.g. situation 1.

I have not considered that the likelihood of the 6 situations may vary from player to player, since they are playing after a certain strategy, they might get into certain situations way more often than in others. But all players are different and no one is ever going to play the same sequence of Polyominos (when not manipulating it to be so). I think we can assume that players will run nonetheless into all 6 situations and that the variety of strategies will make all 6 situations equally likely.

Comment: Could the hole ever be filled in the tetris game?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes sure, it is just a field, that is not occupied by the tetromino i am suggesting. When looking at a 3x3 block it would have the top and bottom row covered and in the middle row only the left and the right are covered. The L-Block would for example cover the bottom row and either the left or the right field in the middle row and not a single field in the top row (when it is rotated accordingly)

Comment: "Least useful to a player" is ill-defined. You can place down any piece, with sufficient vertical room. It may create certain "problems" in an intuitive, but how do you tell if one one situation is worse than another? And given that any piece could be placed in multiple rotations, in multiple places, it'd help to have a numerical measure of how much better/worse one situation is over another.

Comment: Also, I understand that there is no one rotation system in all games of Tetris. Each individual game treats the rotation of each piece individually. This allows for things like T-spins, and other special moves, which vary from game to game. Each tetromino needs to have its own rotation system too.

Comment: Finally, it's worth noting that players don't get into random situations. They will try their best to control their board, and make sure things conform to certain patterns. Analysing the worst outcome in general will therefore be completely useless. At best, you can analyse the worst piece for an individual player. I think your best bet is to test your tetromino against a variety of players.

Comment: @TheoBendit I do not understand your point with the rotation. I would have assumed that you have to place the tetromino in a certain rotation in the end. This means, that shapes, that change when rotated also have multiple ways to being placed, therefore enhancing their probability of being "useful" (antiexample: the 2x2 block for instance does not change after rotation) . I know you are against the term useful but I tried defining it in the question. Probably you have some more feedback, please take a look at it

Comment: There are seven tetrominos: I J L S Z O T. I suspect that most of the occurrences of "tetromino" in the question should instead say "polyomino", but I'm not completely sure which ones. If you could clarify that it would improve the question.

Comment: @IvoVidovic Rotation can affect how useful the final placement can be. Being able to perform a T-spin, for example, makes the T tetromino more useful. The rotation system for the T tetromino makes this possible (it wouldn't be unreasonable, say, to expect the blocks already placed down to obstruct a T-spin move). So, changing the rotation system can change how useful the tetromino is.

Comment: @IvoVidovic As for the measure of usefulness, I find that holes filled or left empty doesn't capture actual usefulness completely. Often holes can easily be filled later, and when I have just tried to eliminate holes, this has often lead me to pile S and Z tetrominos up the sides of the walls, which is not beneficial in the long run. That said, even if it's not actually applicable to Tetris players, there could be a mathematical question in there, with a bit more refinement. However, I don't think I'm the person to answer it.